# Images aren't displayed in Django, but link works in search bar

Tags: python, django, web

I have a little problem with Django and the way to display images with it.
I have a folder, called media and a subfolder called media in media.. yea .. don't judge me.
I've uploaded a image to a post module and tried to load image with

```
<img height="400px" width="400" scr="{{ post.pageImage.url }}" alt="Image">
```

output:

```
<img height="400px" width="400" scr="/media/media/1_g4XcQbA156OfOKVlMox2Tw.png" alt="Image">
```

The output is okay, if I enter the link in the searchbar, it can open the image and load it, but the image isn't displayed on the page.

I've tried a lot of things, :
- MEDIA_URL and ROOT

```
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')


 path('blog/',include('blog.urls')),
 path('project/',include('project.urls')),
 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've tried to make absolute paths, but still, the image stays hidden.

I thank you in advance and hope you can help me.
Nick 'Iywern' Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute `scr` should be `src` in your `img` tag.

Comment: okay.... thanks a lot.. I waited the last hour to solve the problem... thanks a lot for your fast and good eyes :D

Comment: @Liberatys You are welcome. If the answer solved your issue, you should accept it to help others facing similar problem. :)